# Copy all files in his own parent

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hi everyone I need to extract multiple java files, from one directory to a root directory, but I need to preserve de first level. there are many files and many different folders, so any help is appreciated
Here is an example:

What I need to do is make it so that

```
|ROOTDIRECTORY
|    |FOLDER1
|    |    SUBFOLDER
|    |    |     JA.JAVA
|    |FOLDER2
|    |    SUBFOLDER
|    |    |     AAAA.JAVA
|    |FOLDER3
|    |    SUBFOLDER
|    |    |     JAAAA.JAVA
|    |FOLDER4
|    |    SUBFOLDER
|    |    |     |SUBSUBFOLDER
|    |    |         JAV.JAVA
```

Becomes

```
|ROOTDIRECTORY
|    |FOLDER1
|    |    JA.JAVA
|    |FOLDER2
|    |    AAAA.JAVA
|    |FOLDER3
|    |    JAAAA.JAVA
|    |FOLDER4
|    |    JAV.JAVA
```

In this example I have put 2 levels of subfolders, but there are an undetermined number of sub-levels

I think there has to be a way to do this "quickly". There are more than 500 folders and 1,000,000 files.

any idea is welcome

Comment: You'll have a bad time trying to do this in batch files, as the tags imply. It'd be rather easy in e.g. Python, though.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Joshb. Please have a look at the SO help topics at https://stackoverflow.com/help, In particular, see information about creating an MRE at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. SO is not a free code writing service. Please copy and paste your code into the question, tell what it should do, and tell what is is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can imagine this is not exactly what you're looking for, but I have solved this kind of situations in the past, and mostly I did it in the following way (more ore less):

```
forfiles /S /M *.Java /C "cmd /C echo @path"
```

This is not moving anything, it's just showing the paths of the files, with complete directory structure.
I gives a list, containing (according to your example) like this:

```
C:\Folder1\Subfolder\ja.java
...
C:\Folder4\Subfolder\Subsubfolder\jav.java
```

Then I do two things: I keep this list somewhere, and with the copy, I turn this into the following list:

```
C:\Folder1\ja.java
...
C:\Folder4\jav.java
```

I do this by replacing "C:\Folder1\Subfolder\" by "C:\Folder1\", replacing "C:\Folder4\Subfolder\Subsubfolder\" by "C:\Folder4\", using a simple replacement command in a text editor (like Notepad++).

Then I use the column mode of that text editor to create the following kind of commands:

```
mv C:\Folder1\Subfolder\ja.java C:\Folder1\ja.java
....
mv C:\Folder4\Subfolder\Subsubfolder\jav.java C:\Folder4\jav.java
```

I can predict your reaction "Man, that's lame!", but I see two important points:

- In your situation, you want to copy not to the parent folder, but sometimes to the parent's parent folder, which makes the whole thing quite complicated.
- My solution gives you a way to completely verify if everything you're doing is correct before you actually start executing it (you can even just try out some lines and see if it works as expected).

Good luck with it

Comment: Your solution is really useful! Although this is not the most automatic solution, it saves a lot of work if you have some knowledge of notepad ++ or sublime. I hadn't thought to do it like that! (facepalm)
Thank you very much, I hope this can be of help to someone else!